# Linear mixed model fixed and random effects with physiological data

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am working on a data set containing resistance exercise data of multiple participants. I am examining 26 weeks of data points from males and females in different age groups with different training status.

To render the force measurements comparable and plot the progress over time. I normalized the force data (maxForce[i]/maxForce[0]).

The goal is to make ggline plots with pairwise comparisons of the gender including the p values in the plot over time (y-axis: NormalizedForce and x-axis: OneWeekBins).

To achieve this, I need to do the statistics first. I am currently struggling building a valid linear mixed model. My dependent variable is NormalizedForce. In my opinion, gender and TrainingStatus are the fixed factors, while age and OneWeekBin (time) are the random factors.

```
mm <- lmerTest::lmer(data=leg_press1, NormalizedForce ~ gender + TrainingStatus + (1|OneWeekBin))
```

1. Are my assumptions for the lmm correct?
2. How would I posthoc pairwise compare male/females at different time points (OneWeekBin)?
3. What would be a efficient way to add pairwise brackets on the ggline plot?

```
leg_press1 %>% dplyr::filter(TrainingStatus=="unexperienced") %>% ggline(x = "OneWeekBin", y = "NormalizedForce", add = c("mean_se"), color = "gender", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), levels = c("1008", 
"1010", "1034", "1085", "1157", "1278", "1314", "1352", "142", 
"1442", "145", "1505", "1679", "1688", "1692", "1824", "1833", 
"1834", "1856", "1939", "1998", "2044", "208", "2138", "2225", 
"287", "319", "366", "440", "511", "512", "561", "600", "641", 
"680", "688", "837", "851", "889", "923", "935", "967"), class = "factor"), 
    createdAt = structure(c(1671446484.854, 1672151874.9, 1672825525.236, 
    1673431127.42, 1674036436.481, 1674641690.549), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("FEMALE", 
    "MALE"), class = "factor"), age = c(67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67
    ), ageGroup = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("(10,20]", 
    "(20,30]", "(30,40]", "(40,50]", "(50,60]", "(60,70]", "(70,80]", 
    "(80,90]", "(90,100]"), class = "factor"), exerciseId = c("LEG_PRESS", 
    "LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS"
    ), maxForce = c(1068, 1591, 1704, 1983, 1860, 1974), NormalizedForce = c(1, 
    1.49, 1.6, 1.86, 1.74, 1.85), NumberOfVisits = c(1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6), OneWeekBin = structure(1:6, levels = c("1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
    "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
    "24", "25", "26"), class = "factor"), TwoWeekBins = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 3), DaysSinceLastVisit = c(0, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7), 
    height = c(163, 163, 163, 163, 163, 163), weight = c(66, 
    66, 66, 66, 66, 66), healthcondition = c("\"NO\"", "\"NO\"", 
    "\"NO\"", "\"NO\"", "\"NO\"", "\"NO\""), totalWorkoutsCount = c(49, 
    49, 49, 49, 49, 49), maxForce_kg = c(108.9, 162.2, 173.7, 
    202.1, 189.6, 201.2), BMI = c(24.8, 24.8, 24.8, 24.8, 24.8, 
    24.8), ForceperkgBW_Newton = c(16.2, 24.1, 25.8, 30, 28.2, 
    29.9), ForceperkgBW_KG = c(1.7, 2.5, 2.6, 3.1, 2.9, 3), factorAge = c("elderly", 
    "elderly", "elderly", "elderly", "elderly", "elderly"), Frequency = c(26L, 
    26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L), Mean = c(1.03, 1.15, 1.3, 1.31, 
    1.36, 1.39), SD = c(0.13, 0.32, 0.21, 0.34, 0.27, 0.33), 
    TrainingStatus = c("unexperienced", "unexperienced", "unexperienced", 
    "unexperienced", "unexperienced", "unexperienced"), IQR = c(0, 
    0.35, 0.2175, 0.38, 0.44, 0.46), O_upper = c(1, 1.8, 1.71375, 
    2.06, 2.26, 2.275), O_lower = c(1, 0.4, 0.84375, 0.54, 0.5, 
    0.435), IQROUTLIER = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
    "FALSE", "FALSE"), IsExtreme = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
    "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    OneWeekBin = structure(1:6, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
    "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
    "26"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("FEMALE", "MALE"), class = "factor"), 
    exerciseId = c("LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS", 
    "LEG_PRESS", "LEG_PRESS"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
        3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I've provided an answer to your first two questions. The third, about coding to get a particular type of output from `ggplot()`, is off-topic on this site devoted to statistics. Try asking that on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or another site focused on coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup of the linear mixed model is incorrect.

First, time and age are both continuous predictors that apply to all individuals and should be modeled as fixed predictors. Regression splines would probably be a good way to do that, allowing the data to tell you the forms of the associations with outcomes.

Second, your model does not include the most critical random effect in this situation: the individual. Random effects can be used to adjust for correlations of outcomes within individuals, accounting for unknown predictors that aren't captured by the fixed factors in the model.

Third, it looks like all of your data after the first are normalized to the first observation. It's often best instead to use the initial observation for an individual as a predictor for all subsequent observations on the individual, and work in the original scale of the observations.

Finally, this might better be handled with a different type of model than a linear mixed model. This type of situation is covered in [Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long). The type of linear mixed model that you propose makes a particular assumption about the correlations of observations within an individual, an assumption that often doesn't fit the correlations over time in such longitudinal studies. A generalized least squares model, as described in that Chapter, is likely to be a better choice. The R [`nlme` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=nlme) provides a `gls()` function for that. If you really insist on a mixed model, the package's `lme()` function allows for assumptions about within-individual correlations beyond that provided by `lmer()`.

After your model is built correctly, use post-modeling tools like those provide by the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) to make specific comparisons. If you use Frank Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) with its `Gls()` function for the generalized least squares modeling, post-modeling tools are provided within that package.